# How to use Prepared statement with excel import data n Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import, prepared-statement

My question is about the best practice.
I have three tables:

- Users (ID, NAME)
- Cards (ID, NUMBER)
- User_cards (USER_ID, CARD_ID)

Also i have a page with form, where i can import excel file with data. Excel's structure is:

```js
-------------------------------
| Users's name |  Card number |
-------------------------------
| User A       |  12345       |
-------------------------------
| User B       |  67889       |
-------------------------------
```

I want to fill my third table **User_cards**.

The question is: how do i check users and cards exists in DB?

Of course, i know what i can do it by follow:

```php
// check user exists
$user = User::where('name', $userName)->first();

// check card exists
$card = Card::where('number', $cardNumber)->first();
```

But this doesn't look good for server, because code works without any optimization. So, is this okay to use Prepared statement inside the Excel's loop like this:

```php
$statement = $me->getPdo()->prepare($query);
```

or you can to recommend me another better way to achieve these checkings?

I achieved my goal without any prepared statement, but i think that exists more elegant way to do it.
I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Excel (https://laravel-excel.com/). MySQL 5.0.11

Comment: there are users and cards already exists in tables (users and cards)

Comment: Could you solve it with foreign key constrains?

Comment: @Thomas As i know, if i want to insert multiple rows  and even one mistake will be there all data will be return with error, right? What about another situation: i will need to check another things there i can't use only key constrains